# IllegalArgumentException while trying to get Contact Photo Android

Tags: android

I am working on a contact Application, its to show missed calls, dialed calls, the issue comes in when someone whose Cell number is not calls, I have a method that tries to get the caller name based on the cell number then another one which gets the contactID based on the number then the name, number and contactID is saved in a SQLlited Database if the caller is not saved in phonebook the contactID is assigned a random Interger, when I want to retrieve the callers, I call out a method that gets the number, name and contactID, on display I use the contactID to run through the phone and retrieve the caller's display picture, but looking at things the error is coming about when the contact is unsaved, the method that retrieves the caller is unsaved, the random value stored in the contactID variable is matched against the phone if this happens I get the `IllegalArgumentException` Exception on  `context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);`here is my full method that returns display bitmap

```
  public Bitmap openPhoto(long contactId, Context context) {
    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
    Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
            if (data != null) {

                Log.d("BTmap","Bitmap Exists");
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
            }
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    Log.d("BTmap","Bitmap Dont Exist");
    return null;


}
```

could anyone help me on how to overcome this error, when I run the `openPhoto`  method in the `(IllegalArgumentException e)` try catch block Non of the display Pictures load even the ones that are saved in contact book and have images on them, Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it was something very easy, first i had to check if the number that called was saved in my phonebook if not, I set the Name to Unsaved, then in my adapter I had to check if the adapter.getName() value was equal to Unsaved, it it was then there was no need of loading the image, i just had to assign my imageview to null or my default display picture